# Seeking website/service that allows unauthenticated access to published trees?

Tags: website, software-recommendations

Is there a genealogical service/website that allowd access to published trees without forcing guests to create an account?

I've used Ancestry and MyHeritage in the past, and as best I can tell they force everyone to create an account before viewing.

Comment: Hi Patrick – There are loads of popular services that don't require an account for viewing. Additionally there are many tools to generate a website from a GEDCOM, which you can publish online however you want. We generally discourage this type of question because they turn into long lists of links. Perhaps if this question could be transformed into more about the pros/cons of allowing unauthenticated access to published trees, and in that way it would be more productive.

Comment: @HarryVervet - Thanks for getting back to me.  I can appreciate the feedback, but a pro/con list would be of no help.  I can't find any sites at all, and am now even more frustrated with myself since there "loads of popular services" out there somewhere.  I may just be too new to this.  (I am, however, aware of software to host my own should I choose to do that on my own site.)  Thanks for the response, though.  It is sincerely appreciated.  I will leave this up long enough for you to know that I acknowledged your response, and will then withdraw the question from the website.  Thanks.

Comment: Patrick - please don't feel the need to delete this, I didn't mean to suggest you should do so. It may still generate some good answers as is. Since you've had trouble finding such a service, other people may have the same question, and it therefore may be useful to others. It was just my first thought that it might turn into link-list answers but that might not be the case.

Comment: @HarryVervet - OK, thanks.  I'm new to this site and don't want to veer outside of the bounds... I know how difficult it is to keep things on track.  I'll leave it open and see if there are any insights to be had.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify -- your goal is to publish a tree that you can share with someone *without* a requirement that they sign in to view the tree, but you are looking for a solution which is not self-hosted? What are your other requirements?

Comment: @JanMurphy - That is precisely what I hope to find, assuming it exists.  The only other requirement I can think of is the ability to upload some kind of data (any format... GEDCOM, csv, ...) so I don't need to start completely from scratch and enter it all manually.  I am already aware of some self-hosted options, but my hope is to avoid those because of the effort involved.  Thanks!

Comment: I did finally find an example service that may do what I need it to.  Or it will at least meet the minimum requirements.  RootsFinder, which appears to be a relatively new service, tied to FamilySearch.org as best I can tell.

Comment: [WorldConnect](http://wc.rootsweb.ancestry.com/)

Comment: Do you want to maintain a distinct tree, or are you open to a 'tree to rule them all' (i.e. a single connected tree to which multiple people (who may be totally unconnnected to each other) contribute, such as Wikitree.com ?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - That's a good question.  I'd never thought about the possibility of something more collaborative, now was I aware of wikitree.  I always assumed I would just maintain a distinct tree, and I think I'd prefer to do that.  Will indeed give Wikitree a look, though.  Thanks!

Comment: I prefer to maintain a distinct tree but I self-host it. Just wanted to put the shared option out there, though,

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - Out of curiosity, may I ask what you use to self host?  Webtrees? Something coded by hand?

Comment: I don't recommend my solution for anyone who isn't very technically minded: Drupal and web pages produced by my Family Historian package, post-processed using a scriptable editor and then imported using the Drupal Feeds module to further massage the content. Told you you didn't want to know!

Comment: You might find http://www.tngsitebuilding.com a good route to go if you decide to self-host..

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - Actually, I'm following you. :-) My first attempt was a hand managed SQL/PHP driver inside or a WordPress self-hosted site.  It's still up there; link on my profile I believe.  Always an option to do something like that, but it took so much time I'm thinking I might be smart to avoid it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Tribal Pages](https://www.tribalpages.com/) allows this.

Tribal Pages allows visitors to the site to browse published trees as guests - without an account.

As the publisher of the tree you can control the level of information that is available to any viewer.  That is, viewers to whom you give a password and those just browsing as guests.  You can of course hide your tree completely from guest browsers if you wish.

[image: Tribal Pages Privacy Settings]

Tribal Pages has both free and paid account types.